# How to prevent DateTimePicker Valuechanged Event from Textbox Leave Event

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# Windows form have one textbox and one datatimePicker.This textbox has Leave Event and 
when textbox leave event occured,I want to fill value in datetimepicker. This datetimepicker also has ValueChanged Event.
Now my problem is when fill value in datetimepicker from textbox leave event,same time datetimepicker ValueChanged Event also occured.
So textbox leave event occur again.
In this problem, I don't want to occur datetimepicker Valuechanged Event from textbox Leave Event.
This is sample for my code.

```
private void textbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      datetimepicker.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Substring(0, 10); 
} 

private void datetimepicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      //do something 
}
```

Thanks for help. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why don't you remove one of the events or create a property that holds the actual value and do all your code on the Leave event..? can you show what code you have..? and explain what it is that you truly want in regards to capturing data.. you should also put a break point in each event so that you can see which one triggers first.. and decide from there how you want to logically code the rest of your functionality.. does this make sense..?

Comment: This is sample for my code.                                   private void textbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 datetimepicker.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Substring(0, 10);
} 
private void datetimepicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //do something
}                                                                       In this code,when textbox leave event occured,datetimepicker valuechanged event will aslo occur.

Comment: amm don't post the code in the comments post it along with your original question.. edit your question and add it

Answer (score 0):

You may use

- or a boolean variable, that indicates that the value to `DateTimePicker` is set from *outside*, and if appears its `ValueChangedEvent`, just don't care.

  ```
  //PSEUDO CODE
  bool setDateFromOutside = false; //GLOBAL VARIABLE

  public void TextBox_Leave(...){

   setDateFromOutside = true;   //SET TRUE

   dateTimePicker.Value = newDate; //SOME VALUE

   setDateFromOutside = false;  //SET TRUE

  }

  public void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(...){

     if(setDateFromOutside)
        return;
  }
  ```
- or before setting the value to `DateTimePicker` *unsubscribe* from its `ValueChangedEvent`, and subscribe again after.

Comment: Please explan detail for me for your second ans.

Answer (score 0):

Now I resolve my problem by this.

```
private void textbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      datetimepicker.ValueChanged -= datetimepicker_ValueChanged;
      datetimepicker.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Substring(0, 10);
      datetimepicker.ValueChanged += datetimepicker_ValueChanged; 
} 

private void datetimepicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      //do something 
}
```